# Get email in mailcatcher via cy.request

Tags: javascript, cypress, mailcatcher

I'm trying to get email catched by Mailcatcher in Cypress test. Mailcatcher runs at `localhost:1080`, and my app is running on port 3000.

So far I cannot simply use `cy.visit('localhost:1080)` because I am already visiting my app via `cy.visit()` (second unique domain). So I tried this:

```
cy
.request('http://localhost:1080/')
.its('body') //this gives me only a list of headers
```

The email is stored inside `<tbody></tbody>`, but that request above shoves me, that the `<tbody>` element is empty

I'm expecting to get `tr` where email is stored. Any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I hit this exact scenario (testing with Cypress to make sure an email was successfully sent via Mailcatcher) and took the suggested approach of proxying requests.

I noticed that Mailcatcher includes a pretty rudimentary API which allows me to get a list of sent emails via the following URL:

http://localhost:1080/messages

I can then get specifics of each email with requests to (replace `1` with the ID of the Mailcatcher email):

- http://localhost:1080/messages/1.json
- http://localhost:1080/messages/1.plain
- http://localhost:1080/messages/1.html

Thanks to this interface, a proxy is pretty easy.  In my scenario, I used PHP for the proxy and my setup looks something like:

1. Add a new page at http://localhost/mailcatcher_proxy.php
2. Add code in `mailcatcher_proxy.php` to take the args from the request and use cURL to return a request to localhost:1080/messages/
3. Format result and print it in mailcatcher_proxy.php so that it's easily testable via Cypress

Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Not my solution, just borrowed it from google and the github of Cypress (https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/418):

> Email does seem like a common scenario that would require an
>   additional domain. The solution we went for was to use
>   https://mailcatcher.me/ to make the emails available in the browser
>   then add a proxy to webpack-dev-server so that it could be accessed on
>   the same host as the webapp. That way you can treat the email as just
>   another page, visit it and click the link. If you need to hit your
>   backend server you can add an additional proxy to make that available
>   on the webapp domain.

Comment: tried that... making proxy is more difficult, than expected